# How can I call this scale?

Tags: scales

How can I call this scale?

B, C#, D, E, F#, G, A#, B

Because between G and A # it's a tone and a half.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the famous B [Harmonic Minor Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_scale#Harmonic_minor_scale).